# How good is Azure Data Lake for storing an SQL database used for Power BI visualizations?

Tags: azure, powerbi, azure-data-lake, powerbi-datasource

We have an Azure SQL database where we collect a large amount of sensor data and we regularly extract the data from it and transform it a bit with a python script. The end result is a pandas DataFrame file. We would like to store the transformed data in an Azure database and use it as a source of a power BI dashboard.

On the one hand, we want to show the "almost" real-time data on a dashboard (the latency due to the transformation etc. is acceptable, but the dashboard needs to refresh very frequently, let's say once a minute), but we also want to store the transformed data and query it later e.g. to visualize the data only for a given day.
Is it possible to convert the pandas DataFrame into SQL and store it on Data Lake and stream the data from there? I read that it is possible to store structured data on Data Lake and even query it, but I am unsure if this would be the best solution.

(My current task is to choose the best database for storing the transformed data to enable both streaming and querying it later. I am very new in Azure products and I don't have a sandbox account yet to even try around and identify possible pitfalls. I've just figured out that PowerBI does not support DirectQuery for DataLake and I feel like this can be an issue - meaning we would have to query the data on DataLake at first and store it somewhere if we wanted to visualize a subset, is that correct?)

Comment: What do you do in Pandas to transform it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Datalake is not a database, just a store for the data both structured and unstructured, so as mentioned you can't direct query it unless you have some compute capacity (Databricks, Azure Synapse, Azure DataLake Analytics, Power BI Premium with enhanced compute)

Depending on your approach, it may be best to move from Azure SQL Database and Pandas, to Azure Databricks, that can ingest the streaming data, transform, and provide an outputted table that is stored in the data lake. You will then connect Power BI to the Databricks instance and query that. The data will only be available while the cluster is running.
Moving to Databricks, will involve rewriting your Panda code to Koalas, or preferably Pyspark.

You do have the option of using Databricks to write the items back to a Azure SQL Database table. Depending on what transformations you are doing you could keep it all in Azure SQL, or if it is sensor data streaming, take the data through Azure Event Hubs, to Azure Streaming Analytics (does transformations), to Azure SQL Database (store Realtime and historical).